# How to import multiple ods files in mySQL?

Tags: mysql

I have 33 ods files(open office spreadsheet files).
ALL have to be imported to the database01.

At first, it must create the table corresponding to the filename.
After that, which means the next day, (another 33 files would be generated with different data) it shouldn't create the table rather only insert data into the previously created table.

I am using phpMyAmdin. I would love to have the mySQL (script) so that copy and paste directly
from here to there.

Thanks in advance~

Comment: How is the data organised in each spreadsheet?